# Abstract class with scanner

Tags: java, abstract-class

I'm making a game for a CS project and one of the requirements is to only have one scanner for human input. If I make an abstract class "player" that has a scanner object, and create two "human" classes that extend "player", do they each have their own scanner or do they share the "player" scanner? Also, how do I close that scanner when I end the game?

Comment: If you want to share the player scanner, mark it as static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments and your question, I know that you created a `Player` abstract class and two concrete `Human` classes. And you actually want to have one scanner only.

In this kind of situations you should make the `Scanner` field in your `Player` class `static`. That way you only have *one* instance of the `Scanner`. And you should probably add a getter. Let me show you the code:

```
public abstract class Player {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static Scanner getScanner () {
        return scanner;
    }
}
```

And if you want to close the scanner, just call `close`:

```
Player.getScanner().close();
```

Isn't that straightforward?

Another thing that I don't understand, is that why do you create an abstract class? Here is my advice: Make `Player` a concrete class and just create two `Player` objects to represent the two players. I see a lot of people make this mistake. Beginners often like to create classes instead of objects. Inheritance means "is a kind of". Creating objects on the other hand, can be interpreted as "is a". So in your case, Human *is a* Player, unless you want the computer to play as well.

Comment: I have the player class because I also have to implement different AI controlled players. I have concrete method "canmakemove" and abstract methods "getplayertype" and "getmove." Is there a better thing than abstract classes to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> do they each have their own scanner or

If only `Player` class has the `Scanner`, child will not automatically have the `Scanner` except it's accessible for the child/other classes.

> do they share the "player" scanner?

Not directly until you allow them to access the scanner, by means of `static` access or via `getter` or any method.

> how do I close that scanner when I end the game?

You can declare method in `Player` which can do that for you. I guess you want to just close scanner once one of the human *win*.

Moreover, it's worth to note that, `Scanner` is not thread safe, if you are working with a multi threading stuff. So, I suggest that you should better create the separate `Scanner` for individual human, and close it once that human loose the game.

If you are fetching the input from `System.in`, you should have common `Scanner`, otherwise closing one `Scanner` will block all the other `Scanner`s from reading.

You can have single `Scanner` instance, for that you can use [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.

```
abstract class Player {
   private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   public Scanner getScannerInstance() {
       return scanner; 
   }
}
```

Comment: My professor wants us to only have one scanner for the entire program, so if there are two humans playing the game I can't make it so each human gets their own scanner (which is kind of the logical thing to do). To create the scanner I'm using `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);` and each player uses it just by `scan.next();`

Comment: But if I do that, won't there be two scanners, because I'll have to close it for each player using `oPlayer.closeScanner()` and `xPlayer.closeScanner();`?